# How can I mount a child gate between a glass barricade and a bookshelf unit?

Tags: stairs, gates, child-safety

The top of my staircase has a somewhat challenging situation for mounting a gate. On one side is a low glass wall, and on the other is a built in wooden shelf. How can I mount a gate here?
[image: establishing shot]
[image: glass wall]
[image: built in shelf]

Comment: Is that book case built in/screwed _firmly_ down or just sitting there? If it's just sitting there, a kid climbing over the gate has as good a chance of pulling the book case down on top of himself as he does tumbling down the stairs.

Comment: Are you willing to build a simple custom gate, or are you committed to fitting a commercial gate?

Comment: The built in shelf is firmly attached. I could climb on it. 
I’m open to building a custom gate, but I’d probably have to hire it out as my fabrication skills are pretty limited.

Comment: _Everyone's_ DIY skills are limited until they stop hiring things out. :)

Comment: Skimming, on my phone, I didn’t see anyone mention that you can get glass shower door fittings (hinges or plates) that would non-destructively clamp onto the glass balustrade. Get to a glass shower supplier!

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate yeah that’s a good idea. I had been thinking about that too.

Comment: I had substantially the same setup, except that the railing was wood.
I made a 4x4 out of 2 2x4s cut to roughly railing height, slapped a coat of varnish on it, tied it to the bannister, and mounted the gate hinges to the wall.   You only need it for about a year and a half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using glass clamps (thanks to https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/32284/aloysius-defenestrateyou for that suggestion) and some pieces of wood to mount a gate. [image: gate]
[image: latch]

Answer (score 3):

Sandwich the glass between pieces of lumber, to provide sideways support for a "pressure mount" child safety gate.

Top view of assembly:

[image]

(Blue: glass, cream: lumber, green: pressure gate, brown: existing wall panel)

The shelf unit is built in, so could provide the required support. If this is not the case, you could mount **a stud** (a vertical "2x4") with sideways bearing provided by the first step under the unit and an anchor into the ceiling. The 8ft (or so) height of the stud and the 3ft height of the gate reduce the sideways support required of the ceiling anchor.

If you plan to mount a hinge to the sandwich, apply a sill gasket or foam flooring underlayment or tape to the glass before sandwiching it. This will improve friction and spread/smoothen out the point load at the hinges.

Note that that glass is not your usual frail wine glass, it is safety glass which is harder, and it is probably twice (or more) as thick as a window pane. It is stronger than a sheet of plywood, as long as you don't hit it hard with a sharp object.

> Glass has a misleading reputation for being fragile. It is anything but; a piece of 8mm toughened glass will be able to withstand a steel ball weighing 500g dropped from a height of over 2 metres.

Ref: https://technical.iqglassuk.com/glazing-applications/glass-staircases/

Check the specifications and safety information for the gate you have in mind, but pressure gates **are suitable for installation near stairs**. Here is an example (not an endorsement):

> This Safety 1st "Easy-Fit" safety gate keeps your little ones safe from potential hazardous falls near stairways and doorways.

[image]

Fence image: https://www.rona.ca/en/product/safety-1st-dorel-easy-fit-safety-gate-pressure-mount-white-plastic-41817-1986041

Comment: Very nice! I'd venture that a person could even mount a hinged gate to that, especially if some double-sided tape was used against the glass faces. FYI, _all_ studs are vertical. :P

Comment: @isherwood ok, ok, yes.  'tis that fine balance of being correct and making sense to the layperson... I'll edit...

Comment: The diagram adds a lot of clarity to the suggestion. Looking at it again, I might try to rig something up that puts the pressure on the end of the hand rail and the end of the metal channel that is on the floor, and provide a gap so it doesn't touch the glass at all.

Comment: @spuck, note that that glass is not your usual frail wine glass, it is safety glass which is harder, and it is probably twice (or more) as thick as a window pane. It is stronger than a sheet of plywood, as long as you don't hit hammer if hard with a sharp object. I edited my post.

Comment: True, the glass is probably not going to shatter. A sharp point from a hinge screw or other point could take out an unsightly chip, though.

Answer (score 1):

A regular pressure gate could go on the first step below the landing.  You may need to modify the gate to avoid the handrail, or it may fit below the handrail if that's tall enough to be safe.

[image]

Comment: This is the first thought I had. The OP will have to judge if falling that first step is acceptable.

Comment: Looks like your answer was "[borrowed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/261491/34147)". :/

Comment: @FreeMan yeah that's weird, I mean it's not unusual for answer to be similar and not everyone reads every other answer first, but posting with someone else's sketch without specific attribution and highlighting any additional edits might leave the wrong impression

Answer (score 1):

Using several of the ideas here:

1. Locate the stud in the wall at the top of the last vertical step.  if it is aligned with the top step, great, but otherwise screw some 3/4" plywood between two studs such that it goes on the sheet rock wall opposite the wall.
2. Attach the hinge to the plywood or screw a  2x4 to the wall and attach the hinge to that.

[image]

(put the hinges roughly where the green arrows are)

3. Put up a newel post adjacent to the glass wall and secure it to the railing with muffler clamps over epdm rubber.
4. Put the gate in such that it opens onto the landing with the hinge on the wall side.

This will minimize damage to the wall and floor.

Comment: Problem is, that "landing" is already a step down. Perhaps not a problem for a toddler, but a newly-crawling baby?

Comment: I don't think that falling 5-6 inches is a problem for a newly crawling baby.   Might go down to the landing backwards and have some difficulty getting back up the step.  Might also find the step a fun place to learn to pull up and cruise.

Comment: Those houseplants will have to go, though. ;)

Comment: mmmmm..... house plants make a nice snack!

Comment: hey, waitaminute... this image looks like it was borrowed from [jay613's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/261476/34147) which makes this a duplicate of his answer. (Since his says 'answered yesterday' while yours says 'answered 22 hours ago`, I'm presuming his came first.)

Comment: Suggestion: please edit the drawing to show how it is different from jay613 or add your additional arrows etc, and it would be nice to specifically mention that is where you got it from. For instance, in stead of "Using several of the ideas here" you could attribute it as "from the picture in the answer by jay613". It's of course not unusual for answers to be similar, and they still provide a different valuable perspective, and build on each other.

Comment: @freeman I spent dozens and dozens of seconds on that diagram, I deserve credit!   Well, maybe just one dozen. :)  But kudos to gbronner for saying what I thought, but chose to keep to myself, that falling down ONE 5 inch step should not be a big deal for a baby already capable of self-propulsion.

Comment: From the quality, @jay613, I'd assume at _least_ 1.5 dozen! ;) Yes, any toddler should survive a 5" fall. Most of them are more than 5" tall when they're toddling, and they fall all the time. The bounce _all_ the way down the stairs my cause more discomfort, but hey, they're small, they do bounce...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't want permanent anchors.

For the glass wall, I'd use several suction cups, as large as you can find. These may tend to come loose over time so check them periodically and re-stick as necessary.

For the other side, if you can drill small holes in the back, you can loop zip ties through the holes and around the near side of the bookcase. You can "chain" zip ties if necessary to get them long enough. You can then loop another zip tie through each to use as an anchor point. You can later remove the zip ties and only have the small holes in the back.

I'm assuming the back is solid. If it is open on both sides, you can loop the zip-ties without drilling holes but you'll need to block the back so the child doesn't crawl through.

Comment: There may be some sort of soft clamp that could be a viable alternative to the suction cups. It too would probably need to be checked/tightened over time. Note that if at all possible the gate wants to swing _away_ from the stairs, so if the kid manages to bang it loose they are pulling rather than pushing and won't immediately fall into the stairwell.

Comment: There are suction cups used by film crews to mount _expensive_ cameras to the outside of cars. These are _expensive_ suction cups, but they're in the only category of "suction cup" that I'd trust to keep a gate up at the top of the stairs. Most suctions cups available at big box/discount retailers aren't going to hold very well. (Nope, not a clue where to find them, but I'd start with camera/cinematography stores or rental places.)

Comment: And I would suggest using the metal zip ties as being stronger and thinner.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to use a friction-fit gate between the edge of the glass and the face of the bookcase. I see by the lines in the floor that the two aren't exactly facing each other though, so this might be an unreliable solution.

Next easiest would be to mount the gate to the wall by the window, at the edge of the landing before the stairs truly begin. The first step down to the landing would be unprotected, but it presents little risk compared to the risk of tumbling off a couch or other unprotected "heights."

If mounting to the wood bookcase don't mount to the face frame on its front. Mount to the side panel or even the rear instead. To mount to the rear you could fix a sheet of plywood to the rear, extending beyond the side panel of the bookcase. That would give you a virtual "wall" on which to mount the gate hinge. Of course you'll require a gate that is much wider than average to cover the additional distance.

For mounting to the glass you could make a wooden U-shape assembly to clamp to the vertical edge of the glass. Imagine looking down on it from above and seeing both an H and a U shape superimposed. The vertical legs of the H and U are wood panels. The glass sits in the upper portion of the H. The crossbar of the H is bolts to create clamping pressure. The line closing the bottom of the U is a filler piece of wood, similar in thickness to the glass, which keeps the wood side plates parallel so they'll clamp the glass well. This whole assembly provides a place to mount the gate hinges.

Comment: If you have access to a table saw or router, you could use a 4"x4" or similar sized piece of lumber, and cut a slot such that it would fit on the edge of the glass to create the U-shape assembly Greg mentions. A friction-fit baby gate could then hold the lumber in place, or a few daubs of silicone caulking in the slot would provide a secure (and later removeable) hold to the glass.

Comment: I just read the bottom paragraph of your answer, only after posting mine. In any case, the OP now has a visual to go by too.

Comment: Aren’t most pressure fit gates not intended for use at the top of stairs?

Comment: @RobinDavis Good point. See my answer, which I edited just now to address your important point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be concerned about using a pressure fit gate with a glass wall because I think it might break. I appreciate that it's likely to be robust (because it's got to withstand the weight of an adult crashing into it) but if you stress it *and* crash into it, it might break.

Instead, I'd add a newel post and bolt it to the wall at the top of the stairs to avoid having to attach anything to the glass.

Red marks in image are big heavy duty screws to screw through the post into the wall. I'd use the step to partially brace the post too.

You'd need to add something to the bookcase too but then you could then use a normal pressure fit gate. Alternatively, I've seen roller / retractable gates which would probably just screw into the bookcase.

[image]